# How to force a program compiled with '-pg' dump its stat info when it is still running?

Tags: c, gcc, profiling, coredump, gprof

I'm developing in C++(g++) with a non-opensource lib.
every time I run the program, the lib will crash (it double-free some memory).

it's ok for my program now. but it's bad for profiling. I use -pg to profiling the program. As a result of the crash, no 'gmon.out' is generated. so I cannot profile it at all.

Question:
 **How to profiling a 'crashy' program (with gprof).**

*PS. valgrind is ok to analysis a crashy program.*

regards!

Comment: If valgrind works fine, you could just use it for profiling using callgrind and massif tools.

Comment: 1) Fix the bug. 2) Don't expect much from *gprof*. People use it because it's there. *[There are much better ways to do performance tuning.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)*

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey:thanks, the link is very helpful, but as I mentioned, the lib is not open, so I cannot fix it:)

Comment: OK, so if you want to see how you can speed up your code in the time before it crashes, that method works.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function you can call from your program to dump profile data (the same one that's automatically installed as an `atexit` handler when you link with `-pg`), but I don't know what it's called offhand.

The easyist thing to do it, just insert an `exit(0);` call at a suitable point in your program. Alternatively, you can set a breakpoint and use `call exit(0)` in GDB (except that debugging the program will affect the profile data if you stop it in the middle).